# Error Execution (1: 5): ORA-00922: missing or invalid option SET serveroutput ON; in toad

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am using toad. Why am I getting this error message?

```
[Error] Execution (1: 5): ORA-00922: missing or invalid option in toad
```

It is complaining about:

```
SET serveroutput ON;
```

[image]

The code I am using is:

```
set serveroutput on;

CREATE TABLE customers
( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  city varchar2(50)
);

DROP TABLE customers;
/
```

Comment: Just to comment, there's no server output to enable here so you might as well remove the line. It only affects how you want to handle calls to `dbms_output.put_line()` within PL/SQL, in cases where that is not already set the way you want in the client tool's preferences.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson it was just an example. This took me several days to figure out so hoping this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you are using toad. You have to use the lightning bolt instead of the green triangle. Hover your mouse over the two icons. You will see the green triangle says: Execute/compile statement at caret. You will see the lightning bolt says: Execute as script.

[image]

[image]